# C++: Issues in creating threads; error C2672: 'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, compiler-errors

Before marking this as duplicate, I have already seen the other answers and they did not solve my issue.

I have two classes as follows:

A.cpp:

```
class A
{
  public:
          A();
          int getValue()//just an example of a get method 
               {
                     return value;
               }

  private:
         int value;
          // a lot of variables

}
```

B.cpp:

```
class B
{ 
     public: 
            B();
            void addData(string fileName)
              {
                  A* a = new A();

                  //reads the file with the fileName and does alot of stuff
                 //after calculation is over it adds the object to the vector
                list.push_back(a);

              }

           void run()
             {
                 thread t1(&B::simulate, list[0]);
                 thread t2(&B::simulate, list[1]);

                 t1.join();
                 t2.join();
             }

   private:

     vector<A*> list;

     void simulate(A* ptr)
       {
            int value = 0;

            cout << "At first value is " << value << endl;
            weight = ptr->getValue();
            cout << "Then it becomes " << value << endl;
       }
}
```

And then I have a simple main.cpp:

```
  int main()
      {
          B* b = new B();
          b->addData("File1.txt");
          b->addData("File2.txt");

          b->run();

          return 0;

       }
```

I am trying to create two threads by calling the method run(). However, when I try to compile I get the following error:

```
  error C2672: 'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found
```

I checked the other posts but nothing seemed to work for me. Any help would be appreciated.

P.S: I am using the following includes:

```
 #include <thread>
 #include <iostream>
```

and also:

```
using namespace std;
```

I am using other includes but they are irrelevant

Comment: That's a lot of white space....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`B::simulate` is a non-static member function so it requires 2 parameters - `this` and `ptr`, while you supplying only one. You should redeclare it as static since it does not access `this` class members anyway.